# How to map <CR> to <Esc>o in vim insert mode

Tags: vim

In [Practical Vim](http://pragprog.com/book/dnvim/practical-vim), [Drew Neil](http://drewneil.com) emphasised a tip: *Chunk Your Undos* in vim insert mode.

use <kbd>Esc</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> instead of press `<CR>` to force a back to normal mode, so that when you press  next time, you will just undo the line you just opened.

That's really a practical advise! So I tried to map <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to <kbd>Esc</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> in my `.vimrc` file with `imap <C-return> <ESC>o`, but it just not works. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `:imap` should work in GVIM, but in console Vim (both Windows and Linux), <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> **cannot be mapped**.

Some key combinations, like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + non-alphabetic cannot be mapped, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + letter vs. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + letter cannot be distinguished. (Unless your terminal sends a distinct *termcap* code for it, which most don't.) In insert or command-line mode, try typing the key combination. If nothing happens / is inserted, you cannot use that key combination.

Use a different key combination, e.g. `<C-g><Enter>`.